# How to open attached javadoc in external browser

Tags: eclipse

I have two installations of Eclipse, 3.5 and 3.6. In 3.6 when I open attached javadoc it uses the internal web browser, in 3.5 it uses the external Firefox (which I prefer).

I can't find the preference to control this behaviour. Please can anyone help me out here with this little question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The preference you're looking for is in the "General" section; it's called "Web Browser".

A good way to find prefs is to type a relevant word into the search box above the preference tree - see the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I couldn't see for looking. I tried the search box but was searching for "javadoc"

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse(version 2019-12),

Window => Preferences => Browser => General => Web Browser =>

(select radio) Use EXTERNAL web browser =>

(choose checkbox other than Default...) => Apply and Close

[image]